# Ocultar Menu al hacer Click por fuera

Tags: html, css

Tengo un menú lateral un poco simple que tiene un evento Toggle que muestra y oculta dicho menú al darle click en su respectivo botón.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera que me ayudaran a lograr que cuando se haga click en cualquier parte de la pagina fuera del menu, este automaticamente se oculte.

**JavaScript**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#BtMenuDez').on('click', function () {
                $('#MenuDez').toggle('slide'/*'slow'*/);
            });
        });
```

**HTML**

```html
<ul id="menu" style="width: 85px;height: 70px;">
                    <li style="border-radius: 3px;">
                        <a href="#" id="BtMenuDez" style=""><i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i></a>
                        <div id="MenuDez" style="display:none">
                            <ul> 
                                <li><a id="Menu1" href="#Inicio">Inicio</a></li><br />
                                <li><a id="Menu2" href="#Propositos">Propositos</a></li><br />
                                <li><a id="Menu3" href="#5S">5S</a></li><br />
                                <li><a id="Menu7" href="#Mudas">Mudas</a></li><br />
                                <li><a id="Menu8" href="#Poka-Yoke">Poka-Yoke</a></li><br />
                                <li><a id="Menu4" href="#Kanban">Kanban</a></li><br />
                                <li><a id="Menu5" href="#Hansei">Hansei</a></li><br />
                                <li><a id="Menu6" href="#Hacks">Hack's</a></li><br />
                                <li><a id="Menu9" href="#Glosario">Glosario</a></li>
                                <li><a id="Menu10" href="#Contactenos">Contáctenos</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>                
                </ul>
```

Comment: Podrías indicar si utilizas alguna librería (tipo jQuery) o framework (tipo Angular)? O simplemente vanilla JS, para tratar de adecuar la respuesta al contexto y código de tu aplicación

Answer (score 3):

Añade el siguiente código para completar tu parte JavaScript:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(document).on('mouseup', function(e){
    const container = $("#BtnMenuDez");
    if(!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
      $('#MenuDez').hide('slide');
    }
  });

  $('#BtMenuDez').on('click', function () {
    $('#MenuDez').show('slide');
  });
});
```

Lo que se está haciendo es que cuando se haya soltado el botón después de clicar, comprobar si el menú ya está mostrado, y en ese caso, ocultarlo.

Comment: Te dejo un jsfiddle [aquí](https://jsfiddle.net/semagarcia/ghs2b5po/4/)

Answer (score 1):

puedes probar de esta manera:

```js
$(document).mouseup(function(e) 
{
    var container = $('#MenuDez');

    // Si el elemento cliqueado no pertenece al contenedor padre
    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) 
    {
        container.hide();
    }
});
```

Saludos!